# Page not redirecting to given link Mandrill

Tags: javascript, html, mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have created a template to redirect to a specific website . And I am passing website dynamically . So when user click It must redirect to then this dynamic website   `href="*|URL:redirect_link|*"`. But Instead of this website finding link on Mandrill website like this `https://mandrillapp.com/templates/*%7CURL:redirect_link%7C*` . It should open as a new website. What Wrong I am doing ?

```html
        <a class="mcnButton " title="Register and explore!" 
href="*|URL:redirect_link|*" 
target="_blank" 
style="font-weight: normal;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
">Register and explore!</a>
```

Comment: Check the merge tag, is it actually called `URL:redirect_link`? I am not sure you can place colons on merge tag

Comment: @Syfer When I use URL it gives strange fromat like "*%7Chttps://www.google.com%7C*"

Comment: I have full website link in "redirect_link" variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i was wrong. here is the details from mailchimps knowledge base:

`*|URL:YOUR_MERGETAG|*`

> Encodes the value of your merge tag for inclusion in a URL. For
>   example, if you have a list field with the merge tag, *|QUERY|*, and
>   the value includes something like I love monkeys — in your link, use
>   http://www.yourwebsite.com/*|URL:QUERY|* to URL encode the value like:
>   http://www.yourwebsite.com/I+love+monkeys.

more info can be found [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheat-sheet?_ga=1.193870446.2130253608.1417664339#Content-encoding-merge-tags).

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my case I have full web address store in variable like   var redirect_link=www.myweblink.com;   Now How Can I access ?